# Gmail's last always growing counter

Tags: gmail

Gmail has [stopped its evergrowing email storage space](https://www.quora.com/Why-does-Gmail-free-storage-space-not-increase-anymore-beyond-15GB).

What was the storage space counter at before the move to 15GB constant? (Doesn't have to be exact)

Comment: Unless someone got a screen shot, I don't think this question is answerable. That value was generated via JavaScript and was a marketing gimmick more than anything.

Answer (score 4):

According to [the official announcement](https://gmail.googleblog.com/2013/05/bringing-it-all-together-15-gb-now.html) for the new sharing of storage, Gmail *had* a 10GB limit while Google+ Photos and Google Drive shared 5GB before the change. (Confirmed on [this other blog post](https://gmail.googleblog.com/2013_04_01_archive.html) which shows a timeline where the Gmail upper limit was expanded to 10GB on or about April 24, 2012.)

Whether that's what was displayed in the "evergrowing counter" is unknown.